# como recorrer un array

Tags: phalcon

hola tengo un query en el cual traigo algunos datos dentro de los cuales traigo el room_type, al cual deseo quitarle el ultimo caracter.
Ya tengo todo pero no tengo presente como recorrer el array completo e ir buscando el room_type de cada posicion del arreglo para quitarle el ultimo caracter a cada uno.

mi funcion es asi:

```
$phql = "SELECT room_type, iddef_group, 
            COUNT(iddef_reservation) AS total, 
            SUM(IF(id_reserva_opera = 0, 1, 0)) AS Available, 
            SUM(IF(id_reserva_opera != 0, 1, 0)) AS Booked 
            FROM $this->modelRess WHERE estado != 0 AND iddef_group = :idGroup: GROUP BY room_type";
            $datos = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql)->execute(['idGroup'=>$idGroup])->toArray();
```

Ahi realizo toda la busqueda y en lo siguiente quito el caracter que deseo

```
$roomType = substr_replace($datos[2]['room_type'], "", -1);
```

cabe mencionar que en esta ultima parte estoy cambiando solo para la posicion 2 del arreglo pero lo que quiero es que se busque en cada posicion del arreglo el nodo room_type y de le quite el ultimo caracter.

Espero me puedan ayudar saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función `array_map()` y `array_replace()` de php;

```
$resul = array_map(function($item){
   return array_replace($item, ['room_type' => substr_replace($item['room_type'], '', -1)]);
}, $datos);
```

Detro de la variable `$resul` obtienes un array de todos los valores pero con el `room_type` modificado para cada posición donde este se encuentre.

`array_map()` te mapea todo el array y retorna uno nuevo dependiendo de los cambios hechos, y `array_repplace()` reemplaza un el valor de un array por otro.